# Non-AJAX save method for ContentTools

Tags: javascript, php, content-tools

I am using [ContentTools](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools), It has proven to me to be the best free WYSIYG editor available at the moment.  However, one of the biggest problems I'm having is that it seems to insist on saving via AJAX.  This would be fine however *every* other page I have developed does not operate in that way and so it's a bit jarring for my users when suddenly the save button does not post the form and return a success message on a new page.

Is there any way to use "ContentTools" in a standard POST form? Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this ?

Comment: ajax would still post the form - it's just, it's asynchronous ...

Comment: @treyBake — It might post the same data that posting the form would, but that won't trigger a page load as a normal form submission does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The introduction includes a section on how to [save changes](http://getcontenttools.com/getting-started#save-changes).

In it, it collects the data:

> ```
> // Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
> payload = new FormData();
> for (name in regions) {
>     if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
>         payload.append(name, regions[name]);
>     }
> }
> ```

Instead of using a FormData object, add a regular `<form>` to your document.

Instead of appending to the FormData object, generate an `<input type="hidden">` with the data associated with it.

Then, instead of sending the FormData object via XMLHttpRequest, just call the `submit()` method of the `<form>` object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I still get the message "Are you sure you want to leave without saving changes' message after clicking save - is there anyway to disable this?